# Why does this Drools scenario cause an infinite loop?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, business-rules, kie

I'm working on writing a rule set in Drools and the following situation causes an infinite loop by retriggering the rule:

```
rule "My Rule"
    when
        a1:ObjectA()
        b1:ObjectB(field1 > 0 || a1.field1 in (1,2,3))
        ObjectB(field2 > 10)
    then
        modify( b1 ) { setField3(5) };
end
```

The following rule change *doesn't* result in an infinite loop, i.e., when a1 is no longer referenced within ObjectB:

```
rule "My Rule"
    when
        b1:ObjectB(field1 > 0 || field4 in (1,2,3))
        ObjectB(field2 > 10)
    then
        modify( b1 ) { setField3(5) };
end
```

Another scenario which doesn't cause an infinite loop is when I change the `||` to an `&&` in the second `when` line:

```
rule "My Rule"
    when
        a1:ObjectA()
        b1:ObjectB(field1 > 0 && a1.field1 in (1,2,3))
        ObjectB(field2 > 10)
    then
        modify( b1 ) { setField3(5) };
end
```

From the Drools [docs](https://docs.drools.org/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch07.html) I understand that calling `modify(){}` will "trigger a revaluation of all patterns of the matching object type in the knowledge base," but since the field I'm modifying, `field3`, *isn't* used in the LHS conditions, I didn't think it should reevaluate. However, I am faily certain it has to do with referencing `a1.field1` within `ObjectB`, but I can't find a concrete reason why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It matters at the object level, not the field level. Since you modify `a1`, the rule is re-evaluated because it relies on the ObjectA objects in working memory. Note that the docs indicate it will "trigger a reevaluation of all patterns of the matching **object type** in the knowledge base." Not the parameter values.

One way you could avoid this would be to add a constraint like `field3 != 5` on the left hand side. That is:

```
rule "My Rule"
when
  a1: ObjectA( field3 != 5 ) // <-- if field3 is already 5, don't fire the rule
  b1: ObjectB(field1 > 0 || a1.field1 in (1,2,3))
  exists(ObjectA(field2 > 10))
then
  modify( a1 ) { setField3(5) };
end
```

Basically you need to make the rule no longer eligible for re-fire.

Alternatively, depending on your structure you could try to use `no-loop`, but that only keeps the rule from refiring when immediately triggered by the right hand side. If you have multiple modifications/updates/etc going on, you could get into a "broader" looping scenario where multiple rules cause reevaluation. (Example: Rule A does a re-evaluate, no-loop keeps A from firing again; then B causes re-eval, so A can trigger because no-loop does not apply.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made a couple edits. 1) I meant to say modify( b1 ), not modify( a1 ) 2) I added a scenario which doesn't result in a loop. Still confused because in the successful case, I'm still modifying an object type that is in the LHS working memory, so it seems like it should reevaluate there too.

Comment: Yeah what you point out about polluting the ObjectB constraint with references to ObjectA does sound like a likely contributor.